# How to stop Rails (close DB connection) with Apache still running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

Rails 3 on Apache with Passenger: I need to take down Rails so that the DB connection(s) are closed -- this is necessary to perform some regular database maintenance -- but I want Apache up so that it can respond to requests with a static maintenance page.

I am using Capistrano and have seen the threads on how to invoke maintenance mode, but I need to know where to hook my DB tasks, and cannot figure out where.

Any links, or even pointers to where to look in the Capistrano code would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: How are your Ruby processes managed - is it Mongrel, Passenger, Unicorn, or some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capistrano's `deploy:web:disable` task to block access to your site, allowing you to do database maintenance, etc:

```
cap deploy:web:disable REASON="a Database Upgrade" UNTIL="in a few minutes"
```

Then, once you're done:

```
cap deploy:web:enable
```

Comment: Thanks -- this was a pointer I needed to find the code..., but when I read the code (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb) it looks like the Rails app is not really disabled -- the task just puts a file in a place you tell Apache to look at which intercepts all requests.  Good, but it doesn't actually shut down Rails, which I need in order to do database magic.  The restart at the end of a deploy is the only point during which the app is actually down, I think.  Maybe this is really a Passenger issue?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to actually stop the running Ruby passenger processes without stopping Apache completely. Whenever I do database maintenance, it works perfectly fine with the app still running (since no one can access it, there shouldn't be any database activity).

Comment: Thank you.  That's sort of where I landed in my research.  My use case is a staging server which needs to get a fresh copy of the production database, so it's probably fine to stop Apache -- it's just a pain. :-).  BTW, I would vote up your answer, but I am not yet worthy on StackOverflow :-|

Comment: If it's the "correct" answer for you though, you can accept it :)

Comment: Hey @Dylan Markow -- I am now worthy to upvote and mark accepted.  A little SO cleanup found your stranded answer.  Thx again.